# Create the same Blazor app with both WASM and Server-Side

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I would like create a blazor app (two apps actually) that supports both Hosted WASM and Server-Side. They do not need to be a single app that dynamically switch. Actually, I would prefer two separate apps like wasm.myapp.com and server.myapp.com. Users can pick which flavor they prefer to use based on their network environment. Also based on business needs, I could pick one flavor over the other for different scenarios (like browser limitations).

Anyway, is it possible to create two apps that are sharing the same components? Either one app is a shell that references the other app (or vice versa), or two shell apps that reference a third project? Basically the goal is to create one set of UI components/pages that will be shared by both apps.

How do you set it up?

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Put all your components in a Razor class library.

Comment: Razor class library cannot be used as page component right? That means I have to create the same pages in each app.

Comment: No you can load pages from assemblies. `<Router AdditionalAssemblies=...` in `App.razor`

Comment: Wow, never knew about this! So much easier this way, thanks a lot Brian!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to split your code out into a set of library projects and end point Web projects. Providing a comprehensive answer to this question is beyond the scope of a StackOverflow answer. I'll show the basics here with some project screen shots to show project structure and content, and provide a link to the detailed code in a GitHub Repo at the bottom.

#### Libraries

*Blazor.App* contains all the shared code.  I split this out into three projects to apply Clean Design principles so I have:

- *Blazor.Core* - standard Library project
- *Blazor.Data* - standard Library project - dependency to *Core*
- *Blazor.UI* - Razor Library project - dependency to *Core*

#### Blazor Server

The *Blazor.Server.Web* project is the end point project to run the Blazor Server application.  Dependencies to *Core*, *Data* and *UI*.

#### Blazor WASM

- *Blazor.WASM* is a Blazor WebAssembly project to build out the WASM code base - dependency on *Core*, *Data* and *UI*.
- *Blazor.WASM.Web* is a AspNetCore web server to host the API and service point for the WASM application - dependency on *Core*, *Data* and *Controllers*.
- *Blazor.Controllers* contains the controllers -  - dependency on *Core* and *Data*.

The principle differences between the two applications is in the data pipeline.  Interfaces are used to define the Data Brokers to provide abstraction.  The Server project uses the Server data brokers.  The WASM Server API Controllers use the Server data brokers while the WASM application uses the API data brokers.  The different projects load the relevant data broker as the `IDataBroker` service.

Here's a set of screen shots of the different projects:

#### Controllers

[image]

#### Core

[image]

#### Data

[image]

#### UI

[image]

#### Server.Web

[image]

#### WASM

[image]

#### WASM.Web

[image]

Link to the Repo - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Much more complex than I thought but exactly what I needed. Will study this solution in details ... much appreciated!

Comment: NP - it's not as complex as it appears once you get your head around what you're doing.

Comment: Is it possible to use your solution to make 1 Server app for backend and multiple WASM client apps that would be used as a frontend but hosted on different domains ? For example app1.domain.com, app2.domain.com but all can use the same Blazor.Demo.Data ?

Comment: Yes, see one of my GitHub repos - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Medusa

Comment: I am exploring your solution and trying to migrate my Blazor Server project in it but I wonder in what project in Blazr.Demo would you put EF Core entity classes and where would you install EFCore so you can get data from database ?

Comment: Entity classes belong in the Core project/domain - they are normally used throughout the application.  EF core libraries belong in the Data project/domain,  Take a look at my https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Clean repo.  The WeatherForecast data class is under entities in Core and EF libraries are only referenced in the Data project.